# Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is a root of $X^3-2X-2$. Integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_{K}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is a root of $X^{3}-2X-2$. Compute an integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_{K}$.

I have computed the discriminant as $\Delta_{K}=-2^2.19$. I want to apply the algorithm in the book of Frazer Jarvis Algebraic Number Theory. We know that if $\beta=\frac{u_0+u_1\theta+u_2\theta^2}{2}$ is an integral element then its trace and norm is an integer. $Trace(\beta)=\frac{3u_0+4u_2}{2}$. Since $0 \leq u_i<2$ for any i, $u_0=0.$ Then the only possible $\beta$ are : $\frac{\theta}{2},\frac{\theta^2}{2},\frac{\theta+\theta^2}{2}$. But when I computed the norm of all possiblities, Norms are 1/4, 1/2, 1/4 respectively, then they are not integer.

Is there any computational mistakes or what is wrong?

Comment: The norm is $(1/8)(u^3_0 + 4u^2_0 u_2 - 2 u_0 u^2_1 - 6 u_0 u_1 u_2 + 4 u_0 u^2_2 + 2 u^3_1 - 4 u_1 u^2_2 + 4 u^3_2)$ if it helps any.

Comment: So when I use your norm equation, norm of each $\frac{\theta}{2}$, $\frac{\theta^2}{2}$, $\frac{\theta^2+\theta}{2}$ are exactly same with my solutions. It does not help me I think, thank you soo much

Comment: Well, $\frac{\theta^2+\theta}{2}$ is a sum of the other two, so I don't see how it could possibly be part of a linearly independent basis (which I assume must consist of 3 basis elements.)  I don't understand why you restrict yourself to such a small selection of $u_i$, but then I don't have the book.  Also, for instance, if $u_2$ is allowed to be a quarter-integer then $u_0$ can be odd and the trace still come out an integer.

Comment: I have checked the basis on Sage, it must be $\{1,\theta^2,\frac{\theta+\theta^2}{2} \}$

Answer (score 1):

The reason why neither of the norms is an integer is because the elements listed are not algebraic integers. Indeed, for example $\frac{\theta + \theta^2}2$ has $4X^3 - 8X^2 - 4X - 1$ as a minimal polynomial. In fact, it turns out that the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ is equal to $\mathbb Z[\theta]$, which can be deduced by eliminating all possibilites that come from applying the algorithm. So an integral basis of it is $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$.

There is another way to compute the disciminant $d_K$ of the extension $K/\mathbb Q$, which is much more theory dependent, but doesn't involve long computations. In shortly, the only unknown prime power of $d_K$ is the power of $2$. To find out, you make use of the fact that $X^3 - 2X - 2$ is an Eisenstein polynomial with respect to $2$, compute the $2$-adic different of $K/\mathbb Q$ and deduce that $4$ is the highest power of $2$ dividing $d_K$. So as $d_K = \text{disc} f$ we deduce that $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z[\theta]$.

However, I suspect that this method might be too advanced. But, if you want me to, I can include the computation steps, as well as giving you references for the theoretic stuffs.

Comment: So, I understood that, since the polynomial is Eisenstein w.r.t. 2, and 2 is the only prime which its square divides discriminant of K, the degree of ring of integer over $Z[\theta]$ must be 1. Then  the ring of integer is exactly $Z[\theta]$. Am I right?

Comment: @HamideKuru We have that $d_K = [\mathcal O_K:\mathbb Z[\theta]]^2 \cdot \text{disc} f$. Therefore if we prove that $d_k =\text{disc} f$ we have that $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z[\theta]$. Computing $\text{disc} f$ isn't hard since $f$ is a reduced cubic. On the other side, the fact that $f$ is an Eisenstein polynomial with respect to 2 gives you an easy way to compute the highest power of $2$ that divides $f$. It happens that this is enough to determine $d_K$. After which we make the deduction above.